# Hive add archive with symlink

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have been following several tutorials on using Pythons Virtual Environments with a Hive job.  I have having an issue getting this to run as the python complains it can not find the modules.

So my question is how can I add zipped archive of a Virtual Environment to a Hive python UDF, allow all datanodes to find it and include it in running the python UDF

I have been trying to adapt the following url: http://henning.kropponline.de/2014/07/18/virtualenv-hadoop-streaming/

Thank you in advance

Comment: I ended up changing the way I reference python.  Are you trying to run python27?